# Blazor Mono.Linker.LoadException

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, .net-standard

I am trying to import a .NET Framework 3rd party class library into my Blazor WASM application. I figured if the class library wasn't supported I would get the (as stated on the main page of Blazor) PlatformNotSupportedException error.

However, when I am compiling my application I receive this error:

> Error       Unhandled exception. Mono.Linker.LoadException: Error while processing references of 'LibraryA, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..' C:\Users...nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.1.0-preview4.19579.2\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets    204
>
> Error     ILLink failed with exited code
>   -532462766.   C:\Users...nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.1.0-preview4.19579.2\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets 204

Does this mean I cannot use the library? Or can I configure something to make it work? I think the library is compiled to at least .NET v4.5

Comment: How u solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blazor implements .NET Standard 2.0. .NET Standard is a formal
>   specification of .NET APIs that are common across .NET
>   implementations.

Check this [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#code-sharing-and-net-standard) for more detail.

[PlatformNotSupportedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.platformnotsupportedexception?view=netframework-4.8) The exception that is thrown when a feature does not run on a particular platform.

You have to find library which will work with .net Standard